# javaで別のクラスファイルのgetText

Tags: java

sample1.java内に`JTextField text = new JTextField();`でテキストフィールドを作り、ボタンを押すとsample2.javaに書いている別クラス(textget)のプログラムが動き、getText()でテキストフィールド内の文字列を取得するようなプログラムを書いた(書きたい)のですが、単純に`String str = text.getText();`では作成したテキストフィールドから文字列を取得できません。どのように書いたらいいのかご教授ください。

Answer (score 1):

別のクラスのテキストフィールドを`getText()`するのは難しいです。
sample1.javaに、テキストフィールドを取得するメソッドを追加しそこに

```
String str=this.text.getText();
return str;
```

と書けばできると思います。後は、sample2.javaから呼び出せばいいと思います。
当たり前ですが、この場合エラーが出るためsample1.javaのフィールドに

```
JTextField text = new JTextField();
```

のように書けばコンパイルできる気がします。